# GnuPG No pass phrase error

Tags: php, encryption, gnupg

I have tried to encrypt a data using gnupg and PHP. It worked well when i get it done on local system. But When I exported public and Private keys and imported it to my server. It give me error in 
    gnupg_geterror($res) "no passphrase set"

I have tried to decrypt files from Terminal it went well.

Here is my code to decrypt.

```
        $fingerPrint = "";
        if ($request->getParameter('decrypt_as') == "aaaa") {
            $fingerPrint = "8F83434DDDSSSSSDFDFDFFFDDSSSSSSSSD1DD637";
        } elseif ($request->getParameter('decrypt_as') == "bbb") {
            $fingerPrint = "5231B34DDDSSSSSDFDFDFFFDDSSSSSSSSD342236";
        }
        $encryptedData = fread($file, $fileSize);
        $res = gnupg_init();
        gnupg_cleardecryptkeys($res);
        gnupg_adddecryptkey($res,$fingerPrint,"aayyccss");
        $plain = gnupg_decrypt($res, $encryptedData) or die( gnupg_geterror($res) );
        echo nl2br($plain);
```

Please guide me how  can i fix this.

Comment: in gnupg_adddecryptkey() call, are you sure that $fingerPrint is correctly filled? if you dump it just before the call, what's its value?

Comment: Yes it is same as it is required. This code works fine on my local machine but creating problem on server. I just tested it after dumping

Comment: These fingerprints are made up, aren't they? OpenPGP fingerprints are hashes in hexadecimal representation. And: Did you import the keys to the right directory on the server? Each system user has it's own GnuPG home directory, possibly you imported to another one than your web server is reading from.

Comment: I am using ubunut and changed the owner of www-data:www-data; and gnupg is install in root directory.